# VBA Trim a string from a characer if character is found

Tags: vba

This has probably been asked a million times in different variations but I can't find an answer that fits.

I have a string that contains up to 4 MUT IDs ("MUT" followed by 5 numbers, eg MUT00761). If there is more than one ID, they are separated by a space. In some occasion, there will also be a * between two IDs (eg MUT00761 * MUT00684). The * is associated with the MUT ID on its left. I need to remove all those MUT IDs (and their *),if any.

EG, "MUT00111 MUT00222 * MUT00333 MUT00444 *" needs to become "MUT00111 MUT00333".

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself yet?

Comment: The only solution I thought of was a loop on the numbers of * in the string where I would use InStr and Left and concatenations multiple times to rebuild the string after removing the part I didn't want but it seems way too complex for what it does.

Comment: Use `split` (blank as separator). Loop over the result array and copy only elements to your result string if an element is not followed by a element that contains only a star.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Worksheet Formula**

`=IFERROR(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A1,MID(A1,FIND("*",A1)-9,10),"")),A1)`

---

**VBA UDF**

```
Function MUT(S as String) as String
    On Error Resume Next
    MUT = Trim(Replace(S, Mid(S, InStr(1, S, "*") - 9, 10), vbNullString))
    If CBool(Err.Number) Then MUT = S
End Sub
```

Comment: This! Looped it on the number of * in the string and it wors perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1) get the position of 1st MUT with something instr(1,entireText, "MUT"[, …])

2) cut out MUT plus x characters or until the next "," with

3) do again until no MUT is found

Answer (score 0):

Use the Microsoft VBScript Regular Expresions 5.5 library to replace instances of 'MUT *' with vbNullString.

OR

If you don;t grok Regex a simple function like

```
Public Function StripStarredIds(ByVal IdString As String) As String

    Do While InStr(IdString, "*")

        IdString = Replace(IdString, Mid$(IdString, InStr(IdString, "*") - 10, 10), vbNullString)

    Loop

    StripStarredIds = IdString

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a custom function to do this. It may be a bit clunky but this should work:

```
Function StripText(ByVal fullText As String) As String

newText = ""
lastIndex = 1
curIndex = InStr(1, fullText, " *")

If curIndex = 0 Then   '// if no instances of " *" are found then just copy the full text
    newText = fullText
Else
    Do While (curIndex > 0)   '// do until no instances of " *" are found
        newText = newText & Mid(fullText, lastIndex, curIndex - lastIndex - 9)
        lastIndex = curIndex + 2
        curIndex = InStr(lastIndex + 1, fullText, " *")
    Loop
End If

StripText = newText

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use `Split()` function like this:

```
Function GiveItAName(s As String) As String
    Dim res As String
    Dim v As Variant, w As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    v = Split(s, " *")
    For j = 0 To UBound(v) - 1
        w = Split(v(j), " ")
        For i = 0 To UBound(w) - 1
            res = res & w(i) & " "
        Next
    Next
    GiveItAName = WorksheetFunction.Trim(res & v(j))
End Function
```